# Only if x rows exist, add another row SQL

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I cant word my question very well without an example, so my googling hasn't been very successful.

I have a completions table with the columns

```
activity_id | learner_id | completed date
```

I want to get a list of learner_ids where activity_ids 1, 2 and 3 exist.

for context, so I can add an activity completion row for all learners with the activity id of 4, but only to ones that have done 1 2 and 3. I cant work out how to get the data I need!

Comment: group_concat must help

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you've explained it very well *with* your example.

> I  want to get a list of learner_ids where activity_ids 1, 2 and 3 exist

How you do that depends on the structure of the table. Assuming that a unique constraint exists on learner_id and activity_id then you can do this simply with:

```
SELECT learner_id
FROM yourtable
WHERE activity_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY learner_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

If you don't have the unique constraint, then you'd need to use:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id)=3
```

How well this performs would depend on the number of people with all three activities compared with the number missing on or more. In some cases this may be much faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.learner_id
FROM yourtable a
, yourtable b
, yourtable c
WHERE a.learner_id=b.learner_id
AND a.learner_id=c.learner_id
AND a.activity_id=1
AND b.activity_id=2
AND c.activity_id=3
;
```

Comment: thanks for your help - neither are unique. A single learner_id has a row for each completed activity with the learner_id and activity_id in. I want to find all learners that have the 3 rows with the activity id of 1 2 and 3 AND add a row for each of these learner_ids